# Variable Width Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have done quite a bit of digging, and can't seem to find how people handle content restructuring for a variable width element.

For example, if I have a dynamically created horizontal menu it may only have 3 items..

```
<div>

    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And this menu will only have a small width, let's say 400px. I can create a media query to adjust the way it is displayed when the window falls below 400px, however..

If a user adds another item..

```
<div>

    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Location</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Suddenly this menu is larger then 400 px, and so on. My question is, how can I structure my code to handle a variable element width and still control the way that is displayed?

EDIT: When I re-size the browser window on my horizontal menu, at a certain variable width, the inline-block `li` elements drop below the rest of the menu. Instead of letting each element drop as the screen is compressed I would prefer to make the entire menu drop to a vertical orientation. I cannot simply use a media query, since there are variable amounts of menu items. To illustrate the issue try re-sizing the example code in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f5Lv73hp/

Comment: What would be your expected output? There are many ways to do this.

Comment: That is essentially my question, not sure why it is being downvoted. What is the recommended practice? My initial thought would be to use JavaScript to check element width on page load and insert style rules based on those widths.

Comment: I down voted you because you need to give us the expected output, we all have different ways of doing things for different things. Right now your question lacks clarity, you can read about how to ask a question here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For instance, do you want the `li` elements to wrap? Disappear? Get Smaller? change colors? what is it that you want it to do?

Comment: Or are you asking if there is a way to change the media query based off how many `li` elements you have?

Comment: I'm trying to keep my question from being overly specific, as I feel many developers will run into this issue, and I am not sure if the specific output is necessarily important in the context of this question, rather a different question. For my specific scenario I would want the `li` elements the `display: block` and change their width to 100%

Comment: As it sits right now, your question is too broad. You need to narrow it down, otherwise you might get 15 different answers that all "kind of" answer your question. Please update your question.

Comment: 100% of the **parent** or the **screen**?

Comment: width 100% of the screen

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question, so, consider editing your post with more information, including what do you espect...

By the way:

1. **Horizontal Menu**, if you need to keep all list-items with the same width, you can use display-table, there aren't any javascript requirements, just set the list as a table ( see .menu-horizontal css ).

```js
function CasesCtrl($) {

  var case1 = $('#case1');
  $('button', case1).click(function() {
    var list = $('ul', case1);
    var len = $('li', list).length;
    var newItem = '' +
        '<li class="menu-item">' + 
          '<a class="menu-item-link">Item '+ (len + 1) +'</a>' + 
        '</li>'
      ;
    
    list.append(newItem);
  });

  
}

jQuery(document).ready(CasesCtrl);
```

```css
article {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-item {
}

.menu-item-link {
  background: lightseagreen;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
}





.menu-horizontal {
  display: table;
}


.menu-horizontal .menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="case1">
  <ul class="menu menu-horizontal">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="menu-item-link">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="menu-item-link">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="menu-item-link">Item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button">Add Menu Item</button>
</article>
```

Be more specific and I'll edit my answer as you need!

Comment: I think he wants a combination of what you have and what I have, lol. but who really knows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/4p18mxg9/2/

I am using javascript to get the width of the `ul` and applying the width to to media query, that way when you add more `li` it is not dependent on the content.

```
var width = document.getElementById('ul').offsetWidth;

document.querySelector('style').textContent +=
    "@media screen and (max-width:" + width + "px) { li{float: none; width: 100%; background-color: blue; color: white;}}"
```

Added some color, to see easier: https://jsfiddle.net/4p18mxg9/3/